# WPF Listbox custom item image not displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, listbox

I have a problem with my WPF application, I have a `Listbox` which contains a `UserControl` as item.

[image: UserControl]

The `UserControl` have a image (The red square on the picture) with the `Source` bind to the `ImageSource` property like this :

[ListboxCustomItem.xaml](https://windowbinding.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WindowSwitcher/WindowSwitcher/ListboxCustomItem.xaml) :

```
<Image Name="Avatar" Height="56" Width="56" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding AvatarSource}"/>
```

[ListboxCustomItem.xaml.cs](https://windowbinding.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WindowSwitcher/WindowSwitcher/ListboxCustomItem.xaml.cs) :

```
private ImageSource avatarSource;
public ImageSource AvatarSource
{
    get { return this.avatarSource; }
    set
    {
        if(this.avatarSource != value)
        {
            this.avatarSource = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

When I add an item to my Listbox, I set the `AvatarSource` property but the image is not displayed.

I tried to retrieve the `UserControl` via the `Listbox` and I have the same problem but when I set the `AvatarSource` property in the `UserControl` constructor or in the `UserControl_Loaded` method, the image is correctly displayed.

[MainWindow.xaml.cs](https://windowbinding.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WindowSwitcher/WindowSwitcher/MainWindow.xaml.cs) :

```
/// MainWindow::CheckBox_Checked()

ListboxCustomItem itemUC = new ListboxCustomItem();
itemUC.AvatarSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WindowSwitcher;component/Images/feca.png"));

// Add custom item to the listbox
VisualBindings.Items.Add(itemUC);

...

// Test for update the avatar image (custom item)
(VisualBindings.Items.GetItemAt(0) as ListboxCustomItem).setImageSource("feca.png");
VisualBindings.InvalidateVisual();
NotifyPropertyChanged("VisualBindings");
```

Where I'm wrong ?

The project is available on Codeplex at this url : https://windowbinding.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

(Each code label on this topic is linked to the file in codeplex)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to retrieve the UserControl via the Listbox and I have the same problem

Well, this is one issue. If you are binding a list of objects to a ListBox and use a custom UserControl to represent each item, you want to change the object directly, NOT the UserControl (which defeats the purpose of binding).

What I do is I set a property called `Path` on my objects and whenever the `Path` property changes, I start a Backgroundworker, which handles creating a BitmapSource from the source (a file path, though, this might be different in your situation), and then manually set the source of the image in the UserControl when the worker has finished (which is done within the UserControl).

This enables us to:

1. Generate the image using a BackgroundWorker, and
2. Leave the image generation up to the control that is to display it.

As long as you follow these simple guidelines, the image should display fine. If it doesn't, at the very least, it will be easier to debug and see where an issue might occur.